# Using TensorFlow to process separate patches of the image independently

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, computer-vision

I'm trying to use TensorFlow to implement a neural network that works at separate patches of the image independently.

My network consists of an inner network with 3 convolution layers, followed by 2 fully connected layers with 10 output neurons at the end (for 10 classes). This inner network is applied at different patches of the input image independently.

For example, for a `32x32x3` input image, I want my network to take `16x16x3` patches of the image with a spatial stride of 4 pixels and process each patch separately from the others. The result is a a `25x10` tensor that is averaged into a `1x10` final classification of the full network.

My current implementation consists of using `tf.extract_image_patches` to create the separate patches before passing them thru the inner network but the result is extremely slow.

**Is there a way to define the entire inner network as an operation that I then slide over the image the same as it's done with a filter at a single convolution layer?**

My current implementation with a batch size of 100:

```py
def model(data, k_rate=1.0):
    # Patch extraction:
    data_patches = tf.extract_image_patches(data,[1,NiN_size,NiN_size,1],[1,NiN_stride,NiN_stride,1],[1, 1, 1, 1], 'VALID')
    NiN_data = tf.reshape(data_patches, [-1, NiN_size, NiN_size, 3])
    # Convolutional layer 1:
    conv_1 = tf.nn.conv2d(NiN_data, w1,
                          strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                          padding='SAME')
    relu_1 = tf.nn.relu(conv_1 + b1)
    .
    .
    .
    .
    # Fully-connected layer 5:
    local_score = tf.matmul(drop_out, w5) + b5 # -> (2500,10)
    reshape = tf.reshape(local_score, [batch_size, -1, num_labels]) # -> (100,25,10)
    local_ptach_mean =  tf.reduce_mean(reshape,1) # -> (100,10)
    return local_ptach_mean
# Training computation:   
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits( labels=labels, logits=model(dataset, k_rate))
```